# nodejs sort object by numeric value desc with unknown keys?

Tags: javascript, node.js

how can i sort this object by value DESC when the keys are unknown?

```
var themen = {"Eisenbahn":2,"Technik":2,"Mathematik":3,"Automobil":4,"Physik":1,"Computer":2,"Ökonomie":1}
```

Edit:

The following codes generates a Map that suits my requirement, unfortunately it cannot be converted to json via JSON.stringify() and just returns {}

```
themen = new Map(Object.keys(themen).map(function(v) {
    return [v, themen[v]]
}).sort(function(p,t) {
    return t[1] - p[1];
}));
```

any ideas how to make it to json and keep the order?

Comment: not at all, because objects have no order.

Comment: Since object keys have no defined orders, two JSONs with the same data but in different order are for all purposes equal. The question is why do **you** want a specific order?

Comment: yeah simply because it represents a ranking and inside the data structure, i would also like to represent the data in a specific order without having to resort them when i process them in php for example or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Objects have no order, the order in which you add the properties to the object is the order in which they appear.

So can build an object based on the first and adding the properties in the order in which you prefer.

This works:

```
var orderThemen = function (themen) {
  var themens = Object.keys(themen)
  var order = {}
  var output = {}

  themens.forEach(function (key) {
    var auxThemen = themen[key]
    if (!order[auxThemen]) order[auxThemen] = []    
    order[auxThemen].push(key)
  })    

  Object.keys(order).forEach(function (key) {
    var level = order[key]
    level.forEach(function (themen) {
      output[themen] = key
    })
  })

  return output
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So close ...

Change your map line to

```
themen = Object.keys(themen).map(function(v) {
    return [v, themen[v]]
}).sort(function(p,t) {
    return t[1] - p[1];
});
```

`new Map()` creates a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) object which is something else.

**Edit:**

Unless you want the object again ...

```
var result = {}
Object.keys(themen).map(function(v) {
    return [v, themen[v]]
}).sort(function(p,t) {
    return t[1] - p[1];
}).forEach(function(v){
    result[v[0]] = v[1];
});
console.log(result); // => sorted object
```